# How to stream wekipedia in elasticsearch index?

Tags: elasticsearch, stream

For streaming of `wekipedia` i use stream2es in Linux OS when i run the following command

```
./stream2es wiki --target 10.20.1.123:9200/tmp --source http://download.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2
```

it output me the details of help command such as

```
--source is used for determine the source 
--target is used for index default value is this ....
```

, i download stream2es not with curl command, any can say me what is the problems ?